# SQL How to perform conditional batch updates of existing rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot

How do I add condition into the BATCH insert.  I am using statement like following to insert data into the table.

```
INSERT INTO table   (id, date1,date2 ) SELECT ?, ?, ?  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id= ? and COALESCE (date1::timestamp = ?))
```

Above INSERT will add entry into all the columns always.  Is there any way I can have conditional entry into the table. For example I want to insert only date2 if date1 and id is already present.  Goal is to not update the date1 if it is already present.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my understanding of your question: you want to update existing rows in 'table' where 'table' has values for columns 'id' and 'date1'. The update you want to make is to put a date in the column 'date2'.

This will add the current date to 'date2' wherever 'id' and 'date1' are already filled out:

```
UPDATE table 
SET date2 = getdate()
WHERE id IS NOT NULL 
    AND date1 IS NOT NULL
```

Here you can set date2 to anything you want. If you need a date from a different table, you can get it by changing only that line to

```
SET date2 = (SELECT datecolumn FROM othertable WHERE ...)
```